# Mappings are inconsistent with each other. Single Table Inheritance

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, mapping, single-table-inheritance

I get a lot of mapping errors in Symfony's profiler.
I only have this problem with associations with the table inheritance super class.
All the other entities and relations are just fine and working perfectly.

Errors:

```
***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article    
The mappings ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article#buyer and ***\UserBundle\Entity\User#boughtArticles are inconsistent with each other.
The association ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article#category refers to the inverse side field ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Category#article which does not exist.
The association ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article#tags refers to the inverse side field ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Tag#article which does not exist.

***\ArticleBundle\Entity\TBA    
The mappings ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\TBA#buyer and ***\UserBundle\Entity\User#boughtArticles are inconsistent with each other.
The association ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\TBA#category refers to the inverse side field ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Category#article which does not exist.
The association ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\TBA#tags refers to the inverse side field ***\ArticleBundle\Entity\Tag#article which does not exist.
```

Article entity:

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table("articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="***\ArticleBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="article_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"auction" = "Auction", "fixed" = "Fixed", "tba" = "TBA"})
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="***\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="articles")
     **/
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="***\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="boughtArticles")
     **/
    protected $buyer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="article")
     **/
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="article")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_has_tags")
     **/
    protected $tags;
```

User entity

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Snuffelmarkt\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="De door u ingevulde gebruikersnaam is al in gebruik")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Er bestaat al een gebruiker met het door u ingevoerde emailadres")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Snuffelmarkt\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="user")
     **/
    protected $articles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Snuffelmarkt\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy="user")
     **/
    protected $boughtArticles;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $profile;
```

Comment: You got a lot of mistakes $boughtArticles is mappedBy buyer and not user, $tags is inversedBy articles and not article, just reread yourself.

Comment: Thanks i really messed up with the singular and plural "mappedBy", "inversedBy".